# How to apply the same function to multiple ID's?

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox, photo-gallery

I am trying to create a lightbox for my webpage. I am currently following W3schools example of the lightbox: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp

If it helps, the webpage I'm current working on is here: http://students.washington.edu/cdm206k/tinfo230/assign5/multiplayer/multiWeapons.html

I am now able to create multiple lightboxes with the help of S.Serp! 
However, now, I need help showing the caption for each image for all lightboxes. I've tried to create different unique caption ID but it only deletes the caption for each images from the first lightbox and allow the second lightbox to have the captions.

Sub Machines:
[img 1] [img 2] [img 3] [img 4] [img 5]

Assault Rifles:
[img 1] [img 2] [img 3] [img 4] [img 5] <-- I want to make another lightbox for this.

...... and maybe 3 more subsections.

I have created a copy of the first lightbox but there seems to be an interference with the first lightbox and the second lightbox. My problem is that whenever I verify the page, it tells me that I have multiple ID's.

The first one is for the myModal. I've tried using a different name for the id but it still doesn't apply the same function to the second id. The same thing happens for the id captions.

I hope it's not confusing. Any recommendation or help is appreciated. Thank you. 
HTML:

```
        <h1> Black Ops 3 III - Weapons </h1>

        <h2> Primary </h2>
        <h3>Submachines: </h3>

        <section class="row">
          <section class="column">
            <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/kuda.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal');currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor" alt="Primary: Kuda">
          </section>
          <section class="column">
            <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/weevil.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal');currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor" alt="Primary: Weevil">
          </section>
          <section class="column">
            <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/vesper.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal');currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor" alt="Primary: Vesper">
          </section>
          <section class="column">
            <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/pharo.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal');currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor" alt="Primary: Pharo">
          </section>
          <section class="column">
            <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/razorback.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal');currentSlide(5)" class="hover-shadow cursor" alt="Primary: Razorback" >
          </section>
        </section>

        <section id="myModal" class="modal">
          <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal('myModal')">&times;</span>
          <section class="modal-content">

            <section class="mySlides">
              <section class="numbertext">1 / 5</section>
              <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/kuda.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: Kuda" >
            </section>

            <section class="mySlides">
              <section class="numbertext">2 / 5</section>
              <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/weevil.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: Weevil" >
            </section>

            <section class="mySlides">
              <section class="numbertext">3 / 5</section>
              <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/vesper.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: Vesper" >
            </section>

            <section class="mySlides">
              <section class="numbertext">4 / 5</section>
              <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/pharo.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: Pharo" >
            </section>

            <section class="mySlides">
              <section class="numbertext">5 / 5</section>
              <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/razorback.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: Razorback" >
            </section>

            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

            <section class="caption-container">
              <p id="caption"></p>
            </section>


            <section class="column">
              <img class="demo cursor" src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/kuda.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: Kuda" onclick="currentSlide(1)" >
            </section>
            <section class="column">
              <img class="demo cursor" src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/weevil.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: Weevil" onclick="currentSlide(2)" >
            </section>
            <section class="column">
              <img class="demo cursor" src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/vesper.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: Vesper" onclick="currentSlide(3)" >
            </section>
            <section class="column">
              <img class="demo cursor" src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/pharo.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: Pharo" onclick="currentSlide(4)" >
            </section>
            <section class="column">
              <img class="demo cursor" src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/razorback.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: Razorback" onclick="currentSlide(5)" >
            </section>
          </section>
        </section>
        <hr /> ----------------------------------------------- <hr />
        <h3>Assault Rifles: </h3>

        <section class="row">
          <section class="column">
            <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/kn44.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal1');currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor" alt="Primary: KN-44">
          </section>
          <section class="column">
            <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/xr2.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal1');currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor" alt="Primary: XR-2">
          </section>
          <section class="column">
            <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/hvk30.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal1');currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor" alt="Primary: HVK-30">
          </section>
          <section class="column">
            <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/icr1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal1');currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor" alt="Primary: ICR-1">
          </section>
          <section class="column">
            <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/manowar.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal1');currentSlide(5)" class="hover-shadow cursor" alt="Primary: Man-O-War" >
          </section>
          <p></p>
          <section class="column">
            <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/sheiva.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal1');currentSlide(6)" class="hover-shadow cursor" alt="Primary: Sheiva" >
          </section>
          <section class="column">
            <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/m8a7.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal1');currentSlide(7)" class="hover-shadow cursor" alt="Primary: M8A7" >
          </section>
        </section>

        <section id="myModal1" class="modal">
          <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal('myModal1')">&times;</span>
          <section class="modal-content">

            <section class="mySlides">
              <section class="numbertext">1 / 7</section>
              <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/kn44.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: KN-44" >
            </section>

            <section class="mySlides">
              <section class="numbertext">2 / 7</section>
              <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/xr2.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: XR-2" >
            </section>

            <section class="mySlides">
              <section class="numbertext">3 / 7</section>
              <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/hvk30.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: HVK-30" >
            </section>

            <section class="mySlides">
              <section class="numbertext">4 / 7</section>
              <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/icr1.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: ICR-1" >
            </section>

            <section class="mySlides">
              <section class="numbertext">5 / 7</section>
              <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/manowar.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: Man-O-War" >
            </section>

            <section class="mySlides">
              <section class="numbertext">6 / 7</section>
              <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/sheiva.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: Sheiva" >
            </section>

            <section class="mySlides">
              <section class="numbertext">7 / 7</section>
              <img src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/m8a7.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: M8A7" >
            </section>

            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

            <section class="caption-container">
              <p id="caption"></p>
            </section>


            <section class="column">
              <img class="demo cursor" src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/kn44.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: KN-44" onclick="currentSlide(1)" >
            </section>
            <section class="column">
              <img class="demo cursor" src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/xr2.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: XR-2" onclick="currentSlide(2)" >
            </section>
            <section class="column">
              <img class="demo cursor" src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/hvk30.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: HVK-30" onclick="currentSlide(3)" >
            </section>
            <section class="column">
              <img class="demo cursor" src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/icr1.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: ICR-1" onclick="currentSlide(4)" >
            </section>
            <section class="column">
              <img class="demo cursor" src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/manowar.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: Man-O-War" onclick="currentSlide(5)" >
            </section>
            <section class="column">
              <img class="demo cursor" src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/sheiva.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: Sheiva" onclick="currentSlide(6)" >
            </section>
            <section class="column">
              <img class="demo cursor" src="../multiplayer/weapons/primary/m8a7.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Primary: M8A7" onclick="currentSlide(7)" >
            </section>
          </section>
        </section>
```

Javascript:

```
    <script>
    var modalSec;

    function openModal(id) {
      modalSec = document.getElementById('id');
      modalSec.style.display = "block";
    }
    function closeModal(id) {
     modalSec.style.display = "none";
    }

    var slideIndex = 1;

    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = modalSec.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
      var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
      captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
      }
     </script>
```

CSS:

```
   * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   .row > .column {
      padding: 0 8px;
   }

   .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
   }

   .column {
      float: left;
      width: 20%;
   }

   /* The Modal (background) */
   .modal {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      padding-top: 100px;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: black;
   }

   /* Modal Content */
   .modal-content {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #fefefe;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 0;
      width: 90%;
      max-width: 1200px;
   }

   /* The Close Button */
   .close {
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 25px;
      font-size: 35px;
      font-weight: bold;
   }

   .close:hover,
   .close:focus {
      color: #999;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
   }

      .mySlides {
      display: none;
   }

   .cursor {
      cursor: pointer
   }

  /* Next & previous buttons */
  .prev,
  .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      width: auto;
      padding: 16px;
      margin-top: -50px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      transition: 0.6s ease;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
   }

   /* Position the "next button" to the right */
   .next {
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
   }

  /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
   .prev:hover,
   .next:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   }

   /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
   .numbertext {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
   }

   img {
      margin-bottom: -4px;
   }

   .caption-container {
      text-align: center;
      background-color: black;
      padding: 2px 16px;
      color: white;
   }

   .demo {
      opacity: 0.6;
   }

   .active,
   .demo:hover {
      opacity: 1;
   }

   img.hover-shadow {
      transition: 0.3s
   }

   .hover-shadow:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0,      0.19)
   }
```

Comment: where is your second lightbox section (Assault Rifles)?

Comment: I took it out because it didn't work properly. I can try adding it back if it helps?

Comment: i posted the full working answer, please check and accept it if its ok

Comment: That really clarify a lot. I made some changes to the my html and javascript base on your comment.. However, now, I am not  able to get my photos to open to the lightbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have more than just one modal sections, you have to pass the id of modal divs to javascript functions. the sample you mention in w3school will be as following:

The changes are:

» for **first section** ('myModal'):

```
<img ... onclick="openModal('myModal'); currentSlide(1)">
...
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal('myModal')">&times;</span>
 ...
```

» for **second section** ('myModal2'):

```
<img ... onclick="openModal('myModal2'); currentSlide(1)">
...
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal('myModal2')">&times;</span>
 ...
```

» the **javascript** changes:

```
var modalDiv; //new variable to store current modal div

function openModal(id) {
  modalDiv = document.getElementById(id); //keep it in our var
  modalDiv.style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal(id) {
  modalDiv.style.display = "none"; //use modalDiv var here!
}

var slideIndex = 1;
//showSlides(slideIndex); //remove this line, its an error!!

...

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = modalDiv.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"); //use modalDiv var here!
  var dots = modalDiv.getElementsByClassName("demo"); //modified to get proper demo images
  var captionText = modalDiv.getElementsByClassName("caption-container")[0].children[0]; //modified to get proper caption

 ...
```

---

The full code will be as following snippet (see in [Full page] view):

```js
var modalDiv;

    function openModal(id) { 
      modalDiv = document.getElementById(id);
      modalDiv.style.display = "block";
    }

    function closeModal(id) {
      modalDiv.style.display = "none";
    }

    var slideIndex = 1;
    //showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = modalDiv.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = modalDiv.getElementsByClassName("demo");
      var captionText = modalDiv.getElementsByClassName("caption-container")[0].children[0];
      if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
      if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
      captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
    }
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
  }

  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .row > .column {
    padding: 0 8px;
  }

  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }

  .column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
  }

  /* The Modal (background) */
  .modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: black;
  }

  /* Modal Content */
  .modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1200px;
  }

  /* The Close Button */
  .close {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .mySlides {
    display: none;
  }

  .cursor {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  /* Next & previous buttons */
  .prev,
  .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
  }

  /* Position the "next button" to the right */
  .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  }

    /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
    .prev:hover,
    .next:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }

  /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
  .numbertext {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }

  img {
    margin-bottom: -4px;
  }

  .caption-container {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 2px 16px;
    color: white;
  }

  .demo {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }

    .active,
    .demo:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }

  img.hover-shadow {
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  .hover-shadow:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  }
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h2>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal'); currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal'); currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal'); currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal'); currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal('myModal')">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

      <div class="caption-container">
        <p id="caption"></p>
      </div>


      <div class="column">
        <img class="demo cursor" src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise2">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img class="demo cursor" src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Trolltunga, Norway">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img class="demo cursor" src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img class="demo cursor" src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <hr /> ----------------------------------------------- <hr />



  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal2'); currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal2'); currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal2'); currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
    <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal('myModal2')">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

      <div class="caption-container">
        <p id="caption"></p>
      </div>


      <div class="column">
        <img class="demo cursor" src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise2">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img class="demo cursor" src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Trolltunga, Norway2">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img class="demo cursor" src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords2">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: i checked your online site, there are some mistakes: there is one extra `</section>` just before the `<script>` tag. and the most important error is that you specify the id within single quotation marks inside the `function openModal(id) { modalDiv = document.getElementById('id'); ...` but it must be `...getElementById(id)` i.e. change ('id') to (id)

Comment: You are awesome! Got it figured out! Thank you so much. Just one thing, is there a way we can get one unique ID for the caption as well for each section?

Comment: you are welcome! i updated the code to show proper captions. see the 4 first lines of `function showSlides(n)` as `var dots = modalDiv.getElementsByClassName("demo");  var captionText = modalDiv.getElementsByClassName("caption-container")[0].children[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Use class modal to apply javascript to multiple elements
id is for single element which is unique

Comment: I have tried doing this for the modal but it messed up the first lightbox. It didn't show any pictures whenever the picture is clicked.

Comment: He used different ids

Comment: try to pass this parameter to function and it will never mess

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm fairly new to this. Could you possibly show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
function openModal() {
  var a = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
  var i = 0;
  while ( i<a.length){
       a[i].style.display = "block";
       i++;
  }
}
function closeModal() {
  var a = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
  var i = 0;
  while ( i<a.length){
       a[i].style.display = "none";
       i++;
  }
}
```

Use this instead.

Comment: Do I just replace the one I have? and Do I still have to create different ID's for the myModal?

Comment: No need to use id. querySelectorAll(.modal) select all elements with class modal and return an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

You could cut down on the markup and code and make it more easily expandable in the future by using [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) and a single modal element instead of hard-coding an event to each element.

Much slimmer HTML:

```
<div id="modal">
<img class="modal-image">
<div class="modal-button modal-close">&times;</div>
<div class="modal-button modal-prev">&#10094;</div>
<div class="modal-button modal-next">&#10095;</div>
<div class="modal-counter"></div>
</div>

<h3>Submachines:</h3>
<div class="weapons">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000000/fff.png&text=Kuda" alt="Primary: Kuda">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000000/fff.png&text=Weevil" alt="Primary: Weevil">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000000/fff.png&text=Vesper" alt="Primary: Vesper">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000000/fff.png&text=Pharo" alt="Primary: Pharo">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000000/fff.png&text=Razorback" alt="Primary: Razorback" >
</div>

<h3>Assault Rifles:</h3>
<div class="weapons">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000000/fff.png&text=KN-44" alt="Primary: KN-44">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000000/fff.png&text=XR-2" alt="Primary: XR-2">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000000/fff.png&text=HVK-30" alt="Primary: HVK-30">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000000/fff.png&text=ICR-1" alt="Primary: ICR-1">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000000/fff.png&text=Man-O-War" alt="Primary: Man-O-War" >
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000000/fff.png&text=Sheiva" alt="Primary: Sheiva" >
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000000/fff.png&text=M8A7" alt="Primary: M8A7" >
</div>
```

JS:

```
"use strict";

var modal = document.getElementById('modal'),
  modalImage = document.querySelector('.modal-image'),
  modalCounter = document.querySelector('.modal-counter');

document.querySelectorAll('.weapons').forEach(function (weaponCollection) {

  // this uses the spread operator (...) to convert the nodeList into
  // a real array. Most recent versions of modern browsers support this
  // (IE11 doesn't but it is not a recent browser, Edge does). You can
  // convert a nodeList in an ES5 friendly way if you need to...
  var weapons = [...weaponCollection.querySelectorAll('img')],
    totalWeapons = weapons.length;

  weaponCollection.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    var target = evt.target,
      weaponNumber = weapons.indexOf(target) + 1;
    // if the item that was clicked was one of the image tags
    if (target.tagName === 'IMG') {
      modalImage.src = target.src;
      modalCounter.textContent = weaponNumber + ' / ' + totalWeapons;
      modal.classList.add('show');
    }
  }, false);
});

function closeModal () {
  modal.classList.remove('show');
}

document.querySelector('.modal-close').addEventListener('click', closeModal, false);
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/ddgy45z9/)

I didn't implemented the next and prev buttons because it is late and I am tired. I just wanted to show how event delegation can make this kind of thing much less verbose. Implementing the prev and next buttons would probably require some refactoring, I might update the example later. I'll also mention that if you are not adverse to using jQuery, I'm sure there are plenty of ready built plugins that will do this sort of thing for you.